# adMob not showing ads when update

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I published an app on Google Play this morning, adMob worked perfectly but I update my app a few minutes ago 'cause there are some design errors.

So now adMob not working, no more showing ads.
I use "example Id" for debug all time on my phone but I download my app from Google Play there is any problem?
There is a problem or I must wait?

Comment: Without actually looking at the code, no one can tell what is actually wrong. But if you feel that you haven't changed the code for admob, I would suggest that you should wait. It happened with me also. It took about 12 hours before ads were displayed in my app

Comment: I can share my code but that's correct I know 'cause my debug device correctly showing example ads and I use same code with my first publish.